# Laravel Eloquent get all rows that don't exist in array

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am creating a product system and using Laravel as the API. I have a Product model and a File model which have a many-to-many relationship. When assigning files to a product I pass an array of file objects to the Product controller and then check if the relationship already exists. If it doesn't I save this new relationship. Here is the code that does this:

```
if(!empty($requestProductVars['files']) && count($requestProductVars['files'])) {
                    $files = $requestProductVars['files'];

                    foreach($files as $file) {
                        $fileId = $file['id'];
                        $fileRecord = File::find($fileId);
                        if(!$product->files->contains($fileRecord)) {
                            $product->files()->save($fileRecord);
                        }

                    }
                }
                $product->save();
```

This all works fine but what I am trying to implement now is a little bit trickier. If a Product has a file UNASSIGNED from it I want this record to be removed as a relationship to the product. So what I need to do it remove any rows from the pivot table that don't exist in the $requestProductVars['files'] array.

I was thinking of creating separate queries to get all file id's for a project and compare it to the array of objects and removing any that don't exist in the request array  but this seems a little bit resource heavy. Does anyone know of any way that this functionality is achieved in a better way?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using [`sync()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships) method? It will add/keep all rows which are in an array and will remove all other relations:

```
$product->files()->sync($files);
```

`$files` shoud be an array of IDs, for example: `[1, 2, 3, 4]`

If `$files` doesn't contain all relations, you can get IDs of all attached files first and then concatinate this array with `$files`.

Comment: EXACTLY what I was looking for. Thanks a lot.